# MySQL Trigger With SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to make trigger that having SELECT Statement in it but that SELECT query returns more than one rows so, How can I handle that multiple rows in trigger and looping that rows in MySql?

Please Help me.
:Jimit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to do with the results of the `SELECT`, but the most general approach would be to use a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html).